# disable net::http's use_ssl for all new instances

Tags: ruby, ssl, httpwebrequest

I know that I can use the #use_ssl = false to disable the use of ssl for an instance of the net::http, but is there a class method I can set at the beginning of my code so that from that point onward, any new instances of net::http will have ssl switched off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just make a helper method?

```
def http_new(*args)
  a = Net::HTTP.new(*args)
  a.use_ssl = true
  a
end
```

You could also monkey patch the Net::HTTP class"

```
class Net::HTTP
  alias :initialize_old :initialize
  def initialize(*args)
    initialize_old(*args)
    @use_ssl = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Drewrobb, thanks for the tip. I am using some youtube gem and heroku, so the helper method couldn't really work because the call to initiate the instance is inside the gem. So I guess the monkey patching will work?

Comment: Yeah monkey patch is the way to go, but I'm not absolutely certain monkey patching Net:HTTP in your code would affect the youtube gem? Something to test. You could also consider monkey patching or creating a wrapper method for the method(s?) in the youtube gem that are calling Net:HTTP.new.